# What are basic concepts one should know about OAuth, SAML, Microservices?

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml, microservices

What concepts about these topics a mid level java developer should know ?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of a silly question and will most likely be closed as too broad. My general answer is: `As much as possible, of course.` You always want to know as much as possible about any topics that you would consider important for your profession. By the fact that you ask this question I assume that these topics may be important to your career.

The more specific answer is: It depends on where you want to be with your career and personal life. You should of course always learn all topics that would be required in your current job at some point. For deciding if you want to learn additional topics you should consider the following:

1. Will it help your career in the future?
2. Do you have a personal interest in learning it?
3. Are there other topics that would benefit me more?
4. Is it ok to spend time on it for my work / life balance?
5. Is it better to learn a technology or an application domain?
6. Is it fun for me?

...

Also note that in general as a software engineer you won't be able to learn every technology available and you will always have to choose what to learn broadly and what to specialize in. These choices are very important and will define what your earnings potential and future career options are.